# I am trying to create an application using React on my Mac. I am getting a SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: reactjs

My `App.js` code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';

//Pages
import home from './pages/home';
import login from './pages/login';
import signup from './pages/signup';


export class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={home} />
            <Route exact path="/login" component={login} />
            <Route exact path="/signup" component={signup} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

My `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "business-continuity-client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.4",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "type": "module",
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.21.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/standalone": "^7.21.2",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
  }
}
```

I am expecting, when opening my app in a web browser, to have a login, home, and signup page. Instead I get an error in my terminal that states:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

at ESMLoader.moduleStrategy (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:119:18)

at ESMLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:468:14)

at async link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:68:21)
```

I'll appreciate any advice.